# Why performance of javascript is different in firefox opposite to chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I've write this code:

```
function validateForm(){
if (document.getElementById('user_login') != null ){
        var user_login = document.getElementById('user_login');
        if(user_login.value == ''){
            user_login.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            user_login.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
function goToSec(){
    if(validateForm()){
        var first = document.getElementById('first');
        first.style.display = 'none';
        var second = document.getElementById('second');
        second.style.display = 'block';//in firfox this line will execute
    }
}
```

in firefox when `goToSec()` is run by an event, if `validateForm()` return `false` the very last code line will be executed but in chrome everything is ok and control of program will go out the block of code.
I tested it with simple script for example:

```
function f(){
                return false;
            }
            function boo(){
                if(f()){
                    alert('1');
                    alert('2');//debuger meets this line but the code wont be exeuted 
                }
            }
<button onclick="boo()">Ok</button>
```

and Debug it with firefox debuger I found out something wonder, this time debuger meet this line but wont execute it 
How does firefox work? and How we can handle it?

Comment: Did you close the first `alert('1');`?  The browser will wait for an `alert()` to close before executing the next line.

Comment: its working fine for me in both firefox and chrome, can you create some jsfiddle for your problem, and then share it. this will make it faster, to debug for others.

Comment: as I said in simple code firefox debuger meet `alert('2');` and skip `alert('1');'` and no alert show but in my first script very last script will be executed

Comment: why firefox debuger meet the vary last block of code despite `flase` in condition

Comment: please press F12 and debug it step by step